# Jenkins on Ubuntu, to trigger exe file on windows machine

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, msbuild

I have next situation,
Jenkins is installed on Ubuntu machine. I need to run some .exe file that is located on some windows machine (with address 192.168.0.111).
How can I create that specific job in Jenkins ? (note that Jenkins is located on Ubuntu machine).

While searching for solution, I read a lot about  master / slave Jenkins distributions. Can this be resolved with something like that...or does anyone have some better solution ?

Comment: did you *mount -t cifs* the windows share first?

Comment: Did not, can you please explain how to do this ?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-cifs-windows-share/

Comment: Okay, I mounted it without entering the "Password" field and after that he asked me for password. Wrote it down and everything seams okay. What should I do next ?

Comment: I don't know, never used Jenkins/MSBuild on linux, but update your question with the new information plus some more info on your current topology (are you useing a windows Jenkins slave etc) and maybe someone else knows

Answer (score 1):

A master/slave configuration would be easiest to implement. With a Windows slave and a job tied to that slave, instead of being exposed to linux **Execute Shell** build step, you can access **Execute Windows Batch Command** build step.

To setup Jenkins Windows Slave as service, [**read the following guide**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallSlaveasaWindowsservice%28cmdversion%29).
Once setup, you will create a free-style job on your Jenkins interface, same as you would create any Master job, however you will specify that this job executes only on Windows node (slave). Then use **Execute Windows Batch Command** build step to launch your file as you would from Windows command line. Remember to use `%VAR%` instead of `${VAR}` for variables access.

If you really need to send a command to a Windows machine from a *nix machine, there is the question discussing that:
**[Executing exe or bat file on remote windows machine from *nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036300/executing-exe-or-bat-file-on-remote-windows-machine-from-nix)**

Comment: Alright, thank you for you answer. I will review that link you gave me and try to figure it out :)

Comment: If you are executing a dedicated workflow/build/scenario on Windows, a Slave configuration would be best. If you just want to launch a remote exe in the middle of your normal workflow on Linux, then the linked article would be best.

Comment: I need to launch a job that will launch some specific API Importer (builds something, then inserts data into database..etc) which is the .exe file. So I guess I will have to create that job in Jenkins on Windows machine but somehow to trigger it from Jenkins on Ubuntu ?
Just can't figure out how to setup that slave / master connection between those two

Comment: The job is created on your Master as any other job. The difference is that it is tied to slave for execution. Since it executes on Windows environment, instead of using **Execute Shell**, you will be using **Execute Windows Batch Command** and writing batch commands there. Also, since this is windows, you will be using `%VAR%` instead of `${VAR}` for variables. Things like SCM checkout, archiving, emails, all handled the same way as on Master. There is a step-by-step guide to [setup slave here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines)

Comment: The method in that link is good if you have physical console access to remote Windows machine and the machine is always up... however the launching of the Slave is manual. To setup Windows Jenkins Slave as a service, **[read this guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallSlaveasaWindowsservice%28cmdversion%29)**

Comment: Thank you for all informations you provided. I already tried that "Slave step-by-step setup" but something is not working as it should :) Anyway, I will keep trying to create this and come back with results. Once again, thank you for all provided informations

Comment: @Alchnemesis did you confirm that the Windows slave enables the "Execute Windows Batch Command" to be used on a Ubuntu Jenkins machine?